# Why is it so that when tar is executed from the script I get "command not found", (it runs without giving me such output from the terminal)?

Tags: tar, path

The following script does the job of archiving `/home/jerzy/testdir/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

XZ_OPT=-9 tar -cJf /home/jerzy/testdir.tar.xz -C /home/jerzy testdir && \   

echo "testdir/ already archived"
```

it nevertheless gives me the following output:

```
line 3:  : command not found
testdir/ already archived
```

When `XZ_OPT=-9 tar -cJf /home/jerzy/testdir.tar.xz -C /home/jerzy testdir` is executed from the terminal it does its job without spitting out `command not found`. Why is it so that when the very same line is executed from the script I get `command not found`?
Specifying the full path, i.e. `/usr/bin/tar` does not solve the matter.

My environment: Ubuntu Desktop 20.04LTS, `which tar` returns `/usr/bin/tar`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the && followed by \, some spaces, a blank line and a misleading message?

Comment: @JeremyBoden The purpose of the message is to notify the user that `tar` succeded in its task. I find it easier to read code when there are 1-2 blank lines in between the lines. Methinks there is no need for `\` in this code snippet - thanks to the answer of @they . Such usage stems from my bad education.

Comment: `echo "testdir/ already archived" ` - looks like an error message. Surely `echo "testdir/ successfully archived"` would be better?

Comment: @JeremyBoden My bad. It is misleading, indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the `tar` command, you have `&&` and a line continuation.  Or rather, it would have been a line continuation *if* there was no space after the `\`.

Since you have one or more spaces after the `\` at the end of the line, the shell will interpret this as a command whose name is a single space.  This command can not be found.

Testing to run a command whose name is a single space:

```bsh
$ ' '
bash:  : command not found
$ \  # an escaped space
bash:  : command not found
```

(The name of the command not being found is the second of the two spaces between `bash:` and `: command not found`.)

The solution is to remove the spaces after `\` so that the backslash is the last character on the line (escaping the newline).

Alternatively, remove the `\` altogether.  There is no need to have a line continuation at this point in the script.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

XZ_OPT=-9 tar -cJ -f ~jerzy/testdir.tar.xz -C ~jerzy testdir &&
echo '"testdir" archived'
```

I'm using `/bin/sh` here rather than `bash` as nothing in the script requires `bash`.  I also took the liberty of using the tilde syntax for accessing the home directory of the user `jerzy`.  This way, your script would work even on systems where home directories are located elsewhere, as they are on, e.g., macOS.  If you meant to refer to the home directory of the *current* user, I would have used `"$HOME"` instead.

---

There are a few ways to make it more obvious that the `echo` command is depending on the success or failure of the `tar` command.  For example, you may indent the `echo` command:

```bsh
XZ_OPT=-9 tar -cJ -f ~jerzy/testdir.tar.xz -C ~jerzy testdir &&
    echo '"testdir" archived'
```

... or, if it does not result in a too long line, simply do not break the line:

```bsh
XZ_OPT=-9 tar -cJ -f ~jerzy/testdir.tar.xz -C ~jerzy testdir && echo '"testdir" archived'
```

You could even turn it into a full-blown `if`-statement:

```bsh
if XZ_OPT=-9 tar -cJ -f ~jerzy/testdir.tar.xz -C ~jerzy testdir
then
    echo '"testdir" archived'
else
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Your `if` based one would not propagate `tar`'s failing exit status. You'd need some `else exit 1` or `else exit`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Wouldn't `else false` be better, at least if we consider this as a replacement for only the given AND-list in a generic script?

Comment: Depends what we want. But it seems to me that if that `tar` fails the script should probably abort. So maybe even `tar ... || exit; echo succeeded; ...` would be better if there's more the script is doing afterwards.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The reader has options now, and extra background given by your comments. Thanks for the input (and for that extra edit just now)!